# created xml but missing heading and xmlns

Tags: xml, vb.net, vba

I am creating a xml document from within excel 2013 so am using vba to replicate another xml document. I have written some code below that creates and save my xml document. The data within the document is fine and structured correctly. However there are two things missing. I have referenced Microsoft XML version 3.0 in my project.

First line that is missing is from xml document but in the one I am trying to replicate is,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

The second line is also different. I have,

```
 -<MyXmlReport>
```

the file I'm trying to replicate has,

```
 -<MyXmlReport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchem-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
```

Below is my code (its just for testing at the moment). I though when you create a DOMDocument the first line above would be added to the document?

**Update**

I added the line below objDom.setProperty and the namespaces appear to be there when I use the getProperty("SelectionNamespaces") method but when I open the document I still do not see the namespaces?

```
 Public Sub CreateXMLDoc()

 Dim objDom As DOMDocument
 Dim objRootElem As IXMLDOMElement
 Dim objMemElem As IXMLDOMElement

 Set objDom = New DOMDocument

 objDom.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""" & " xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"""

 ' create the root element
 Set objRootElem = objDom.createElement("MyXmlReport")
 objDom.appendChild objRootElem

 ' create security element
 Dim objSecElem As IXMLDOMElement
 Set objSecElem = objDom.createElement("Security")
 objRootElem.appendChild objSecElem

 Dim str(1 To 3) As String
 str(1) = "A"
 str(2) = "B"
 str(3) = "C"

 For i = 1 To UBound(str)
     Dim objProp As IXMLDOMElement
     Set objProp = objDom.createElement(str(i))
     objSecElem.appendChild objProp
     objProp.Text = i
 Next i

 objDom.Save "C:\Somelocation\myFile.xml"

 end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the XML declaration as a processing instruction (David already covered this):

```vb
Dim xmlDecl As IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction
Set xmlDecl = objDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""")
objDom.appendChild xmlDecl
```

The namespace declarations are attributes on the root element, so you can add them using:

```vb
objRootElem.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
objRootElem.setAttribute "xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create *Processing Instructions* or the XML Declaration. [Try this](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200108/msg01342.html):

```
Dim declaration

Set declaration = objDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no' ")

objDom.appendChild declaration
```